# Why does GPS not work on certain devices if the screen is off?

Tags: android, gps

I am developing an Android application. I find that GPS fails to work on certain devices (Samsung Galaxy S version 2.2.1, Samsung Galaxy Ace version 2.3.6 Gingerbread, Motorola Diffy  2.2) if the screen is off. It works fine on other devices (HTC Wildfire 2.3.3), even if the screen is off. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if that happens, but I faced a similar problem with accelerometer. It won't give any sensor readings when the screen is locked. So what I did was, whenever I want the sensor readings, I just took the wake lock every 5 minutes, so the screen gets ON and then I get the sensor readings. Should be useful to you. The user need not manually do anything.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.but I don't want to On screen.I want to on Gps  like music player that plays songs whether screen is on or off.No user interaction is required

Comment: It worked on Galaxy Tab when I tested. If it doesn't work, then there is no other choice left.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK) `WakeLock` lets you use sensors when screen is off (unlike other wakelocks). All it does is keeping CPU up all the time.

Comment: thanks for reply but this concept will consume lots of battery power because my app will run every time in background

Comment: that's the price and it's high ;) AFAIK this is the way to do it. Unless there is some fancy custom service in API that I am not aware of (yet)